# How do I get onActivityResult to run in an Adobe Air native extension?

Tags: android, apache-flex, air, air-native-extension

I am writing an extension that will allow a Flex application to access Android's native image picker. I am able to launch the image picker activity without issue, but after it returns to the caller, which is an FREFunction object, onActivityResult is not called. Because of this, I am unable to figure out what image the user has chosen.

When I use the exact same contents of the FREFunction in a native Android app, The app works fine, and I am able to retrieve the URI of the chosen image in onActivityResult. How can I get onActivityResult to fire, or at least retrieve the information returned by the image picker activity?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another, simpler solution:

- In ANE extension's native java project, include
  **runtimeClasses.jar** from AIR's lib folder (*AIR\lib\android\lib*), along with **FlashRuntimeExtension.jar**. This gives you access to
  AIR's AndroidActivityWrapper class.
- Since some interfaces in **runtimeClasses.jar** are defined as
  protected, you need to make them accessible to your extension. So,
  create two interfaces in com.adobe.air package namespace:

---

**ActivityResultCallback.java**

```
package com.adobe.air;

import com.adobe.air.AndroidActivityWrapper;

public abstract interface ActivityResultCallback extends AndroidActivityWrapper.ActivityResultCallback
{
}
```

---

**StateChangeCallback.java**

```
package com.adobe.air;

import com.adobe.air.AndroidActivityWrapper;

public abstract interface StateChangeCallback extends AndroidActivityWrapper.StateChangeCallback
{
}
```

- You can now register some callbacks in our extension:

---

**ExtensionContext.java**

```
package com.company.extension;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import com.adobe.air.ActivityResultCallback;
import com.adobe.air.AndroidActivityWrapper;
import com.adobe.air.AndroidActivityWrapper.ActivityState;
import com.adobe.air.StateChangeCallback;
import com.adobe.fre.FREContext;
import com.adobe.fre.FREFunction;

public class ExtensionContext extends FREContext implements ActivityResultCallback, StateChangeCallback
{
    private AndroidActivityWrapper aaw;

    public ExtensionContext() {
        aaw = AndroidActivityWrapper.GetAndroidActivityWrapper();
        aaw.addActivityResultListener( this );
        aaw.addActivityStateChangeListner( this );
    }
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent ) {
    }

    @Override 
    public void onActivityStateChanged( ActivityState state ) {
        switch ( state ) {
            case STARTED:
            case RESTARTED:
            case RESUMED:
            case PAUSED:
            case STOPPED:
            case DESTROYED:
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration paramConfiguration)
    {
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, FREFunction> getFunctions() {
        Map<String, FREFunction> functionMap = new HashMap<String, FREFunction>();
        return functionMap; 
    }

    @Override 
    public void dispose() { 
        if (aaw!=null) {
            aaw.removeActivityResultListener( this );
            aaw.removeActivityStateChangeListner( this );
            aaw = null;
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: This is a much better and more complete solution than @Omatic's one and wholly better than Adobe's own documentation, it really should be marked as the correct answer.

Comment: Didn't work for me. When I referenced runtimeClasses.jar in the project then got that: 

`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/adobe/air/AndroidActivityWrapper`

After I packaged runtimeClasses.jar into the final jar got another problem:

`java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for void com.adobe.air.AIRWindowSurfaceView.nativeSurfaceCreated() (tried Java_com_adobe_air_AIRWindowSurfaceView_nativeSurfaceCreated and Java_com_adobe_air_AIRWindowSurfaceView_nativeSurfaceCreated__)`

Comment: @MagaAbdurakhmanov did you fix that error? I have exactly the same error now, trying to figure out how to fix it

Comment: @Rod.C sadly, no. I did a workaround without using onActivityResult in my app.

Comment: I was looking at this issue again, and I found what was wrong before. Actually is working fine for me. There are 2 consideration, you have to include runtimeClasses.jar in the classpath, but you don't have to compile and include the jar in your app, adt will be in charge of that. Second consideration, I have to use "apk-captive-runtime" for ADT, if I try to use a shared runtime the app throws some other errors

Comment: What about `onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus)`.  Can that be detected by ** AndroidActivityWrapper**?

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to start an activity from the FREFunction, and then use that activity's onActivityResult function to perform the desired actions that would require the returning activity's data.

From there, you can use StatusEvent to send information back to your Flex application. Make sure to have listeners for StatusEvent, and proper functions to handle the data based on the event's label.

Note: Adding extras to the activity that is to run your onActivityResult may cause the activity to never be called. Instead, create public static fields in your FREFunction for the activity to call.

In addition, ensure that the context being used in the activity is the FREContext used by the native extension handler.

Comment: Anyway you could elaborate with some code examples? I'm having a similar issue.