# In-App Billing v3 with Adobe Air

Tags: android, air, in-app-billing, air-native-extension

I'm trying to implement in-app billing (v3) for Android devices using Adobe Air with Native Extension. My problem is I don't know how to subclass default flash wrapper `Activity` (which is generated @ flash compile time and named `AppEntry`, AFAIK) in order to override `onActivityResult()` method, what is needed for correct in-app v3 implementation.

How to do that?

Comment: Answered here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8766698/how-do-i-get-onactivityresult-to-run-in-an-adobe-air-native-extension

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems its almost impossible, shame on Adobe. The only solution I have found so far is to launch some temporary `Activity` every time I'm about to buy something and launch GooglePlay from it, so I can override its `onActivityResult` method.

I have found such implementation [here](https://github.com/pozirk/AndroidInAppPurchase).